# Some pitfalls about floating point addition in binary

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have some question about adding two floating point in binary. Can anyone tell me which step I did wrong?

Following are two floating number

```
sign  exponent    fraction
1     11101101   10000001101000011010011
0     11101110   01010100001001110010110
```

First step. align exponent ( need to align to big one )

```
1     11101110   11000000110100001101001  (exponet + 1 and shift right)
0     11101110   01010100001001110010110
```

Second step. rounding (because I shift right and ignore number = 1/2, and least significant bit is 1, so we need add 1)

PS: this rounding rule is at video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbxSTxhTmrs 
when 9:33

Third step. addition (for fraction part)

```
  1.01010100001001110010110
- 0.11000000110100001101010 (add 1 for rounding up)
-------------------------------------------
  1.00100110101011001011000
```

Last

because `1.00100110101011001011000` is normalized, so fraction is `00100110101011001011000` and exponent is `11101110`

but answer in exponent is `11101101` and fraction is `00100110101011001011001`

are there any wrong in my each step? Thanks.

Comment: Aren’t both exponents negative - so second should be aligned to first (i.e. which is largest/least negative)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your computation, mostly forgetting hidden bits and performing the computation on an incorrect number of bits.

```
A:1     11101101   (1).10000001101000011010011  
B:0     11101110   (1).01010100001001110010110
```

Step 1: 
Add hidden bits
Align exponents
Pass to two's complement representation

Note that, as you replace the sign-absolute value by 2's complement, you need one extra bit.

```
A=exp(11101110)   -(00.110000001101000011010011)  
 =exp(11101110)     11.001111110010111100101101  
B=exp(11101110)     01.01010100001001110010110
```

Step 2: perform the addition
As you may have a result >1 (or (<-2), this must be done with an extra bit with sign extension of the operands. You should not perform operand rounding before. If operands are close and of different sign, you may loose precision bit(s).

```
(ca)  11  11111    1 1111  1 11
      111.001111110010111100101101  
     +001.01010100001001110010110
      -----------------------------
      000.100100110101011001011001
```

Step 3: renormalize to get a number between 1 and 2, adjust exponent and transform number to sign absolute representation.

```
m=1.00100110101011001011001 exp=exp-1=11101101
```

Step 4: Round result and renormalize if required.
(nothing to do here).

So m=(1).00100110101011001011001 exp=11101101

It gives the expected result. And it is possible to double check.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  union floatint {
    int i;
    float f;
  };
  union floatint a;
  a.i=0xf6C0D0D3;// 1111 0110 1100 0000 1101 0000 1101 0011
  union floatint b;
  b.i=0x772A1396;// 0111 0111 0010 1010 0001 0011 1001 0110
  union floatint c;
  c.f=a.f+b.f;
  printf("0x%x\n",c.i);
  // gives 0x76935659 = 0111 0110 1001 0011 0101 0110 0101 1001=0 11101101 00100110101011001011001
}
```